# Is there a way to get the dhcp Vendor Class from dnsmasq's dhcp-script

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq

Is there a way to get the dhcp Vendor Class from dnsmasq's dhcp-script?

I created a basic script that echos the args and env, and it's not there

```
dnsmasq-script[9471]: args=old *********** 10.159.163.213 **********
dnsmasq-script[9471]: DNSMASQ_INTERFACE=eth0
dnsmasq-script[9471]: DNSMASQ_TIME_REMAINING=15130
dnsmasq-script[9471]: DNSMASQ_CLIENT_ID=**************
dnsmasq-script[9471]: PIDFILE=/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid
dnsmasq-script[9471]: DNSMASQ_LEASE_EXPIRES=1684152717
dnsmasq-script[9471]: PWD=/
dnsmasq-script[9471]: LANG=en_ZA.UTF-8
dnsmasq-script[9471]: INVOCATION_ID=e8fdd34925824cd6903b2279c3d45f15
dnsmasq-script[9471]: SHLVL=1
dnsmasq-script[9471]: DNSMASQ_DOMAIN=****************
dnsmasq-script[9471]: JOURNAL_STREAM=8:664371
dnsmasq-script[9471]: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

I did a `tcpdump`, and I can confirm the dhcp client is sending a dhcp Vendor Class.